# Select2 multiple, on select again do not remove

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I', using select2 with option for multiple selections. Although what i've noticed is that if you have an option selected if you select it again it removes it from the array. Anyway i can disable that ? say disable maybe the option upon selection ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You must not make that thing. You will break accesibility and if user wants to remove a choice because a mistake give posibility to make it. It's not problem with this, there are not security issues, and I think that's not reasonable.

Comment: There is always the `x` button next to the selection box that is inserted

Comment: What's the reason because you need to make that you are describe?

Comment: Client just doesn't seem to think it's useful ( would cause trouble * )

Comment: OMG! Some clients are ignorants. I understand you. If clients said to us that he wants a webpage with artificial fires, our task is too to said them that artificial fires is not a programatically task. Call chinese people XD. I don't recommend to you to make that task, but if it's absolutely neccesary you must to modify the plugin that's not good idea.

Comment: Could not agree more with you on it. Didn't wanna dig so deep into the plugin. Thought maybe someone had some kind of a quick solution or setting. Appreciate the help

Comment: I use now select2 and chosen in a project and I need to modify the plugins to make crazy things like this. I don't find any better solution. But I will investigate right now if you can make it without touch the plugin

Comment: Sometimes we need to tell the clients what we can do in a webpage and what we can't do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `stopPropagation` outside the plugin to avoid selecting a selected option.

```
 $('.select2-container--default .select2-results__option[aria-selected="true"]').on('click mousedown', function(event) {
       event.stopPropagation();
 });
```

Test it please and tell if it works, otherwise we need to modify the plugin. Plugin hasn't got any event or option to make this task (as I tell you in comments, that's a bad idea even if the client said that is good)

Comment: Yeah, you need to modify the plugin as I tell you in comments. I have very experience with this kind of plugins and if there is no option to use outside the plugin there is no another solution than modify plugin. Otherwise, I insist that is a very bad idea make this kind of weird things.

Comment: Yeah, thank you for the time you put into this. i'll just let the client know it's not possible at least for now

Comment: If you have no other way to make this, I can help you to modify the plugin. I make it in the past so many times (it's because I tell you that's no good idea, but if you needed I can help you anyway)

Comment: Appreciate it, but i'd prefer to put him on hold for now on such a small thing than having shudden errors now and then and having to go through a 4k line JS code that i haven't written myself :)

Comment: Ok, I'm suscribed in this topic to following in the future. Good luck!

Comment: Theres a solution now, just FYI: https://forums.select2.org/t/how-to-not-open-dropdown-when-deselecting-option-in-multiselect/1132/2, just tested it and it works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Maybe another way is to add another option to select each time that the user clicks in a option... with same label and other key... very bad idea haha

[image: anotheroption]

Comment: I think that's a comment, not an answer :)